# ASP.Net getting userid inside global file

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, global-asax

i have looked around and still didn't get an answer to this.

I have a ASP.NET application and it uses windows authentication. Web.config is properly configured:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

I am getting the userid in method:
WindowsAuthentication_Authenticate(object sender, WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs e)

The code that is getting the userid:

```
var userId = String.Empty;
        //Dispalys the UserName from AD.
        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User;
        User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
        if (User != null)
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            username = username.Substring(username.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

            CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;
            userId = (textInfo.ToTitleCase(username));
        }
```

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User is always null in this case.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the arguments of `WindowsAuthentication_Authenticate` method is of `WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs` type. One of its properties is `Identity`, so You should probably be able to access user name by writing `e.Identity.Name`.

Reference links:

- WindowsAuthenticationModule.Authenticate Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationmodule.authenticate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- WindowsAuthenticationEventArgs Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationeventargs_properties%28v=vs.100%29.aspx